# page not found when reload the page in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

yes this question been ask some people as well and this issue trigger to 
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

why I asked this again ? I did create file .htaccess in root folder like that Link tell, but it still doesnt work, this is I my.htaccess in the root

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

do I create wrong name file ?

my vue app doesnt has server though just like static website

so I have a route like this

```
mydomain.com/detail/:name
```

when I go to that page it was good, but when I refresh again, it was not working again and it said `page not found`

I deploy this app on `surge` and `GitLab Pages` (using their ci/cd) it was same result ,

what is the matter then with my vue ??

Answer (score 0):

Surge does not support .htaccess files.  The file you added is specific to servers running Apache.

From their docs, there's two ways to do this.

1: Adding [redirects](https://surge.sh/help/adding-redirects)

> ROUTER files are part of Surge Plus. When you publish, you’ll be prompted to upgrade your project right from the CLI.

Unfortunately, you need an upgraded account to access this feature.  They also don't have any examples of more complicated redirects, so you'd need to try these yourself, or reach out to their support.

2: Adding a [200.html](https://surge.sh/help/adding-a-200-page-for-client-side-routing)

> To take advantage of this with Surge, add a 200.html file into the root of your project. Now, when a request for a URL comes in where you don’t have a static HTML page, it will reach your 200 page instead, allowing you to use your client-side router.

Your 200.html file should contain enough HTML and javascript to mount you app and allow your router to take over.  You could start by copying your apps index.html, and placing the contents inside a 200.html located in the same folder as your index.html.

Comment: my issue is problem on surge and GitLab Pages, I deploy to there only for dev and before production I deploy to s3, when I deploy to gitlab page, it was same result, I think my issue is in my router :(

Comment: Is this working correctly in S3, and does S3 or Cloudfront have any redirects set up?

Comment: I just deploy it , it does working at all and not display but not get any error, I don't know why this vue has problem, maybe I miss something in module

Comment: The issue you're describing in your post is caused by the difference between Vue's client side routing, and your hosts server side routing.  Your Vue app knows that /detail/hmilbradt exists, but the server tries to find that file, doesn't find it, and returns an error.  You need to tell your server, using a language it understands, like the link I posted, to redirect all files back to an `index.html`, so that your Vue app can take over the routing.

Comment: can u give me example to redirect it on vue router ?

Comment: vue-router should automatically handle this when the app starts